# NHibernate custom IIdentifierGenerator with Transaction

Tags: nhibernate

Simple Question can I do something like that:

(I don´t know an alternative way to this, since NHibernate doesn´t support nested Transactions)

```
public class GetNextSequence : IIdentifierGenerator
    {
        public object Generate(NHibernate.Engine.ISessionImplementor session, object obj)
        {
            using (var nSession = SessionFactoryWrapper.SessionFactory.OpenSession())
            {
                using( var tran = nSession.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.Serializable))
                {
                    var update = nSession.CreateSQLQuery("update counter set last_one = last_one + 1 where item like :item");
                    update.SetParameter("item", "account_contact.account_contact_id");

                    update.ExecuteUpdate();

                    var query = nSession.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT last_one FROM counter WHERE item LIKE :item");
                    query.SetParameter("item", "account_contact.account_contact_id");
                    var lastOne = query.UniqueResult();

                    tran.Commit();
                    return lastOne;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

or is this something I should not do, and if so why not?

Comment: This looks awfully a lot like hilo. Can you not use that instead?

Comment: yup, maybe I need to use this table and increment the counter +1 and I need to be sure that nobody can read the old counter value! Is this possible with Hilo?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what hilo is plus it gives you additional benefits.what type of mappings you using? XML fluent or mapping by code and I will post an answer

Comment: Mind you do you have other external systems also using this table?

Comment: yup I have external systems using this Table, is it possible to ensure they get the right key with Hilo? And I´m using Fluent Mapping and XML for StoredProcedures!

Comment: Unfortunately AFAIK HILO is designed to work within NHibernate by itself.

Comment: OK, do you think there are any pitfalls in my Implementation of IIdentifierGenerator?

Comment: HILO with low = 1 would suffice. see here for row per entity http://stackoverflow.com/a/11402990/671619

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
public class GetNextSequence : IIdentifierGenerator, IConfigurable
    {
        private string _item;

        public object Generate(NHibernate.Engine.ISessionImplementor session, object obj)
        {
            using (var nSession = SessionFactoryWrapper.SessionFactory.OpenSession())
            {
                using( var tran = nSession.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.Serializable))
                {
                    var update = nSession.CreateSQLQuery("update counter set last_one = last_one + 1 where item like :item");
                    update.SetParameter("item", _item);

                    update.ExecuteUpdate();

                    var query = nSession.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT last_one FROM counter WHERE item LIKE :item");
                    query.SetParameter("item", _item);
                    var lastOne = query.UniqueResult();

                    tran.Commit();
                    return lastOne;
                }
            }
        }

        public void Configure(NHibernate.Type.IType type, IDictionary<string, string> parms, NHibernate.Dialect.Dialect dialect)
        {
            parms.TryGetValue("item", out _item);
        }
    }
```